# yard to generate markdown files instead of html?

Tags: ruby, gitlab, markdown, yard

I am trying to automate documentation using markdown compatible wiki without having a separate server.
I have ruby code with yard compatible documentation. If I run
`yard doc`, it generates html files in `./doc` directory.

Would it be possible to generate `.md` files from the code using `yard`? So that I can simply add these files to GitLab or GitHub wiki or other markdown supported wiki?

Sorry if the question is repeated.

Comment: That does not make sense. The purpose of markdown is for human to write and let the computer generate html from it. If you have html from the beginning, why would you need a markdown file?

Comment: I do not have any html. I have documentation in code as in with comments. So basically need a parser to parse comment and generate .md files out of that? Does that makes sense?

Comment: Would http://20over20.com/post/15841809298/changing-yards-markup-format-to-markdown-or help?

Comment: This has been available since `0.7.4` you just need `redcarpet` or `rdiscount`

Comment: Already tries that. It seems that it is there to support documentation written in markdown. So it will parse your markup if it is in markdown and still generate html pages.

Comment: Yeah, anything that handles Markdown will almost certainly output HTML (or possibly some other non-Markdown format). I've never seen any tool which outputs Markdown that isn't converting from another format. I suppose you could convert to HTML and then back to Markdown, but that's less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on this question doing my initial research, but haven't found an answer here. It may sound strange, that some people want to convert documentation no to html, but to markdown instead.

But there are plenty of software that can't render HTML, but works with markdown.

I have developed rdoc plugin to do that.
https://github.com/skatkov/rdoc-markdown